# Select multiple items in Flex Tree control without pressing the Ctrl key?

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, tree

I'm trying to modifty the Flex Tree control to allow a user to select multiple items by just clicking each of the desired elements (ie I don't want them to have to press Ctrl or Shift).  If the user clicks a selected item a 2nd time, it will deselect it.  Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to do this with a datagrid, since they are both based on list it will work for you too

[How can I get a datagrid to behave like the ctrl key is active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344665/how-can-i-get-a-datagrid-to-behave-like-the-ctrl-key-is-active)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple custom component of ur own. Here is the code:

package com
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import mx.controls.Tree;

```
public class ForceCtrlTree extends Tree
{
    override protected function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        event.ctrlKey = true;
        super.mouseClickHandler(event);
    }
    override protected function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        event.ctrlKey = true;
        super.mouseDownHandler(event);
    }
}
```

}

Import this package into your project.
Then declare the tree component as follows:

Now you need not click ctrl to select multiple objects.