# SelectItem Method in spark Datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, flex-spark

I am enabling multiple row selection with clicking checkbox Item renderer.

this works for  extending `mx:Datagrid` ([other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346844/842112))

```
override protected function selectItem(item:IListItemRenderer,
                                                   shiftKey:Boolean, ctrlKey:Boolean,
                                                   transition:Boolean = true):Boolean
            {
                // only run selection code if a checkbox was hit and always
                // pretend we're using ctrl selection

                if (item is CheckBox)
                    return super.selectItem(item, shiftKey, true, transition);
                else //Avenir Cokaj 23/06/11: this enables the flex's natural selection
                    return super.selectItem(item, shiftKey, ctrlKey, transition);

            }
```

But there is no `super.selectItem` in `s:Datagrid` So how to enable control key on spark datagrid?

Comment: We can use [Spark checkbox grid](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2011/03/spark-checkbox-datagrid-with-drag-and-drop-support.html) alternate to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [selectionMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#selectionMode) property. No more subclassing required. In your case, you would want to set it to `multipleRows`.

```
<s:DataGrid selectionMode="multipleRows" />
```

Other values are:

- none
- singleCell
- singleRow (default)
- multipleCells

I believe they are pretty self-explanatory.

Now if you wish the rows to be multi-selected with a single click (as if the control key were constantly pressed), you can do this by subclassing DataGrid like this:

```
public class MyDataGrid extends DataGrid {

    override protected function grid_mouseDownHandler(event:GridEvent):void {
        event.ctrlKey = true;
        super.grid_mouseDownHandler(event);
    }

}
```

We just intercept the event and set its `ctrlKey` property to always be `true`.

Comment: I think you dint get question correctly.. i don't want manual press of ctrl key and select multiple. see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2344665/842112 i want same in spark datagrid

Comment: it works but item editors in grid are not working while ctrl key is enabled.